# Changing div css color via onclick and by using getElementByName

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is what I've done so far using CSS,Javascript and HTML..  if you click the red circle, it will change to yellow 
which is working but, I just want to add some functions, if the user clicks anywhere outside of the div, then the div will go back to its original color.

How can I do it?

here's my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="circle" name="color" onclick="changeColor()"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#circle{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #F00;
    border: 2px solid ; 
}
```

JS:

```
function changeColor() {
    document.getElementsByName('color')[0].style.background="#FF0"; 
}
```

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Show us your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You can add the css style class to your element on click event and remove when clicked out side.

Comment: add another div around your "circle" and give it 100% width/height, and z-index lower than your circle. then add on click to it ...

Answer (score 4):

The most flexible way of doing it is to add a class `.active` to your CSS, and apply that class to your circle on click.

If you want to catch for clicks outside the circle, you'll have to set the event listener on the body, and then check `e.target` to see if it matches your element.

```
var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
document.onclick = function(e) { //Set the event handler in JavaScript, not in HTML.
    if (e.target === circle) { //e.target is the clicked element.
        circle.classList.add("active");
    }
    else {
        circle.classList.remove("active");
    }
}
```

Then in your CSS:

```
#circle{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #F00;
    border: 2px solid ; 
}
#circle.active {
    background: #FF0;
}
```

Toggle means that it would apply the class if it's not there, and remove it if it is. Now if you want to add extra styles to happen on click, you can simply add them to the `#circle.active` selector.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xob62ssp/3/)**

Comment: He wants to change color when user click outside the div and not on the div.

Comment: He doesnt want the toggle effect. He wants event to apply if clicked outside.

Comment: `e.target` is an HTMLElement, how can you compare it with its `id` into the `if` statment?

Comment: @Fractaliste I don't. I compare it with `circle`, which is another HTMLElement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function changeColor() {
            var dd = document.getElementById('circle');
            dd.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0';

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="circle" id = "color"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#color{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #F00;
    border: 2px solid ; 
}
```

JS

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(document.readyState !== 'complete') return;
     var node = document.getElementById('color');
     document.body.onclick = function(evt){
         if(evt.target.id == 'color'){
           node.style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
         } else {
           node.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
         }
     }
};
```

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/litibezaxazu/1/)